# Auto-renewal Subscripton receipt validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing Auto-renewal with trial period,Now I'm testing with Sandbox Account.I Have a couple of questions,Please help me.

1.After purchasing I'm validating receipt whether he is free trail or not, but receipt "is_trial_period" is false, I need to know whether user is in free trail or not?

2.If user deletes the app and re-install again in the same device or in another device can i get receipt again?

3.If i wont get receipt after re-install how can i unlock the feature for subscription as he already subscribed?

4.If user cancels the subscription in the trail period, how would i know that is cancelled?

5.If user cancels Subscription, If i restore the purchases, then shall i get purchases in restore transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I may answer some of those questions:

1. If you get receipt by Sandbox account, receipt will only active for 5 minutes. Probably is_trial_period will be true on real users.
2. If user deletes the app from device and re-install with same devices you can retrieve receipt but if user install in different device he/she must be restore purchase with Apple ID which bought subscription.
3. Check answer 2.
4. Receipt has expires_date and you can check it if user cancelled or not.
5. Probably related to 4th answer.

I hope those can help.

Comment: Thank you @Mert Serin for answers these are really helped me.Regarding 5th question If user cancels Purchase in trial period and reinstall the app in another device, i can restore purchase with with apple id, but my question is can i get expires date in restore?I think we won't get purchase date and expireDate details, i explored on SKPayment​Transaction object which we will get on delegate method when we try to restore purchase.If we get ExpireDate in receipt we don't have any problem.If user cancels the purchase i need to block the feature when trial period expired.

Comment: Can i test In-app purchase with live App id and valid credit card details stored in Device settings for debugging to know how it really works?